# Swift : Assets folder not working properly after recovering it back from bin

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently i deleted my Assets.xcassets folder and when i recovered it back old images worked just fine but when I am adding new images, they are displaying on StoryBoard but not in the app.

I searched and found a solution that i have to select my app in 'Target Membership' in Assets.xcassets.

[image]

That worked for some viewControllers but some controllers like the **Splash screen is not working**

Tell me if I am missing something? Maybe I have to reference the assets folder somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, actually it just took some restarts of xcode and macbook and it started working correctly again.
I think the only needed work was to check the 'Target Membership'